# Dynamic pickerRow Titanium Studio

Tags: android, ios, windows-mobile, dynamic-data, titanium-mobile

I am an absolute beginner, I am trying to develop my first app. I went through the Lynda.com.Titanium.Mobile.App.Development.Essential.Training.

After that I draw down what I want to achieve, basically a multi selector, where the main fields are:

Continent, Country, State, AirField, Lat, Lng

dynamically linked

so I started to google around and I found the following peace of code:

> var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
>   {//PICKER
>
> ```
> var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
>     selectionIndicator: true
> });
>
> var data = [
>     {country: 'US', cities: ['Miami', 'Orlando', 'LA', 'Ny']}, 
>     {country: 'Canada', cities: ['Toronto', 'Ottawa', 'Quebec']}, 
>     {country: 'UK', cities: ['London', 'York', 'Oxford', 'Bath']}
> ];
> var rows = [];
> for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
>     var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
>         title: data[i].country,
>         cityArray: data[i].cities
>     });
>
>     rows.push(row);
>
> }
> picker.add(rows);
>
> picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){
>     Ti.API.info(e.row.title);
>     Ti.API.info(e.row.cityArray);
> })
> ```
>
> win.add(picker);
>   }
>   win.open();

but i do not think it is working as it should, it does not display the second picker, any help, any suggestions, pointers?

cheers

Answer (score -2):

Your code has a few syntax errors.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    selectionIndicator: true
});
var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
var column2 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

var data = [
    {country: 'US', cities: ['Miami', 'Orlando', 'LA', 'Ny']}, 
    {country: 'Canada', cities: ['Toronto', 'Ottawa', 'Quebec']}, 
    {country: 'UK', cities: ['London', 'York', 'Oxford', 'Bath']}
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var row1 = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
        title: data[i].country,

    });
    column1.addRow(row1);
}

for (x in data[0])
{
    var row2 = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
        title: data[0][x].val,

    });
    column2.addRow(row2)
 }

picker.add([column1,column2]);

picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    Ti.API.info(e.row.title);
    Ti.API.info(e.row.cityArray);
});

win.add(picker);

win.open();
```

I've modified the code a little.

This should return the full left picker, and the options for the first City on the 2nd picker.

Your event listener will have to change the 2nd picker when the first changes.

Notice the addition of "columns".

I also cleaned up some syntax errors.

I haven't tested this code, but its should lead you in the right direction.

Also, this should help: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker

Comment: Cameron, thank you very an sorry I just saw your post. I will try asap, and post back the result.

Comment: No problem man! I didn't test that code, so there may be errors. Should be a good starting point tho. Another thing to look at would be the Kitchen Sink. You can download it from the Titanium Studio dashboard.